# Problem deploying R Shiny app using `DesktopDeployR` - "Windows Script Host" error, run.wsf not found

Tags: r, shiny

I tried `DesktopDeployR` on my computer with the default Shiny app of author repo and it works great (https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR).
Therefore I ziped it up and send it to my other laptop to see how this one handles things. It is basically the same OS (Windows 10) but without R installed. On this second laptop I got the below error after launching the bat:

[image]

I do not understand this error since the run.wsf file is where it is supposed to be. On GitHub there a similar issue (https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR/issues/19) which unfortunately does not fix the issue (default app has a `session$onSessionEnded()` and I am not launching the batch as an administrator either since it is a company laptop). Any other clues?

Comment: *"default Shiny app of your repo"* ... whose repo?

Comment: Just added the source